# Free windows inventory spreadsheet

Tags: windows, gratis, spreadsheet

I need a simple to use spreadsheet to use for inventory tracking that can be updated daily.  I need rows and columns, unlimited rows, 7 columns.

Comment: Is there something about LibreOffice's Calc that doesn't work for you? It supports 1,048,576 rows. Not unlimited, but probably adequate for inventories. https://www.libreoffice.org/

Answer (score 0):

What about Kanban? Kanban was invented just for that.
There are many tools offering Kanban Boards. One of my favorites is Trello (https://trello.com/).

You can create columns (as many you like). You do not have rows but items in a column. You can move the items between the columns, assign users, add information.

Trello is a wab app and no spreadsheet. So this is not really an answer to you question, but i hope it helps anyway.